# Flash logo in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, flash

Does anyone know how I can add a logo in the form of a Flash movie to my Wordpress blog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just edit your header.php file which resides in your theme folder. Then you can add your code of swf logo or any plugin code for same wherever you want it.

Comment: tryed that it won't load could it be a problem with the path ?

Comment: it can be a problem of path, just check out in firebug whether that swf is loading or not. You can check it in Net tab of firebug.